# Finding a Closed Form for a Grade School Art Project

Tags: calculus, closed-form, envelope, art

Hello Math StackExchange! When I was in grade school, our math class did an art project where we drew many straight lines to make what appears to be a curve on the outside (pictures attached). I've been curious about the resulting curve for at least a year, and upon dedicating time toward it, I still can't get a satisfactory solution (besides a brute force method with the max(x,y) function). Is there a closed form for the limiting case of this curve? Is a closed form impossible?

Case of 5 lines:

[image]

Case of 100 lines:

[image]

Comment: What is the rule for creating such lines ?

Comment: @conan it looks like the rule is to choose some real number, $x$ and natural number $n$. The first line is the line connecting the points $(0,x/2)$ and $(x/2,0)$ then the next line connects $(0+x/n, x/2 -x/n)$ and $(x/2-x/n, 0+x/n)$, and keep rotating like this until one component in each coordinate reaches $0$ again, and then duplicate and reflect all the lines about the line $y=x$

Comment: I think you might be talking about an envelope of a family of lines

Comment: Lookup the [envelope of a family of curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)#Envelope_of_a_family_of_curves). In your case $F(t,x,y) = y - 1 + t + \frac{1-t}{t} x$, and after doing the calculations you get the envelope $(x-y+1)^2 - 4 x = 0$ $\iff y = x + 1 - 2 \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=1.$ It is a special case of $x^p+y^p=1.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for a closed form for the function defined as $$y(x) = \max_{p\in [0,1]} \Big(1-p-\tfrac{1-p}{p}x\Big)$$ for $x\in [0,1]$. Notice that we can rewrite the expression in parentheses as follows: $$1-p-\tfrac{1-p}{p}x = 1+x - 2\sqrt{x} - \Big(\sqrt{p} - \sqrt{\tfrac{x}{p}}\Big)^2$$ Because perfect squares of real numbers are always nonnegative, we can argue that this expression is always at most $1+x-2\sqrt{x}$. Furthermore, this value is actually achieved when $p=\sqrt{x}$. Hence, we have that $$y(x) = 1+x-2\sqrt{x}$$ and voila:
[image]

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful OP if you also say how you got to that function instead of just proving that it is the maximum and that that value is achieved.

Comment: @VincentBatens How do you mean? I got the definition of $y(x)$ straight from OP's screenshots. Or are you referring to the motivation behind the algebraic manipulation?

Comment: Nevermind, I need more sleep :) Your solution is perfect

Comment: OMG you are a math master (mathster) thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

To answer Vincent Batens' question, what I first did was consider a very discrete solution like in picture 1 with an arbitrary n lines (because of Mr. Sanderson as you all know). Every curve can be parametrized by the value i/p (i in mine, p in Dyer's) for any given x; that's tedious algebra that is really annoying to simplify but is clear enough. The max function can be explained verbally:

> For every line that can be parametrized at this x value, one of them has the highest value (which is what defines the height of the curve), so pick that as the curve.

Answer (score 0):

**parabola**

Note that our graph $y=x+1-2\sqrt{x}$ is part of a parabola.

[image: parabola]